# How can I avoid recursive Automapper calls with a self referencing object?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a class Employee:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Employees1 = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReportsToId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee ReportsTo { get; set; }
}
```

And a view model for this:

```
public class EmployeeEditModel : MappedViewModel<Employee>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? ReportsTo { get; set; }
}
```

`MappedViewModel<T>` declares a method:

```
public class MappedViewModel<TEntity>: ViewModel
{
    public virtual TEntity MapToEntity()
    {
        return (TEntity)Mapper.Map(this, GetType(), typeof(TEntity));
    }
}
```

When I call `MapToEntity` in an action method, as such

I get an exception from AutoMapper with the message:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Int32 -> Employee System.Int32 -> Leave.Data.Employee
>
> Destination path: Employee.ReportsTo.ReportsTo
>
> Source value: 5

My mappings are defined as follows:

```
public static void RegisterMaps()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeCreateModel>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeCreateModel, Employee>();
}
```

The double reference `Employee.ReportsTo.ReportsTo` screams out to me that this exception is somehow caused by some sort of cyclical mapping quirk, but I what can I do about this? At very least I would like omit `ReportsTo` from the mapping and simply do this manually after calling `MapToEntity`. How can I even to this, and rather, what should I do for this pattern of AutoMapper problem?

Comment: What's your mapping definition looks like?

Comment: @xing I've added more code to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do more than simple `Mapper.CreateMap` as it won't magically figured out how to convert between `EmployeeViewModel.ReportsTo` (`int?`) and `Employee.ReportsTo` (`Employee`).

Either create a mapping between `int` and `Employee` or use the `ForMember` method to tell AutoMapper how to convert the `ReportsTo` property.

Comment: Yes, the attempted conversion from int? to Employee was actually a bug. The source field (in the view model) should be `int? ReportsToId`  and not `int? ReportsTo`. I found this last night, but though I'd give someone chance to answer. Thanks.